# Only use relative linenumbers in current buffer for Vim in Terminal

Tags: vim

I want to use relativenumbers only for the current buffer and when Vim is that active pane in Tmux. This is so that I can use gdb in one pane and vim in another and be able to see the actual linenumbers in the Vim C sourcefile.

This is what im trying right now:

```
autocmd BufLeave * : set number                                                             
autocmd BufEnter * : set relativenumber
```

This does however not give me the wanted behavior since nothing happens when I switch out of Vim.

Answer (score 3):

you need `setlocal`, try these two lines in your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufLeave * : setlocal norelativenumber
autocmd BufEnter * : setlocal relativenumber
```

Comment: In addition, if you want to set-up some `FocusGained`/`FocusLost` autocommands and have them work inside tmux then you'll need to use something like the [Terminus plugin](https://github.com/wincent/terminus) or similar (disclaimer: I wrote Terminus).

Comment: Does not work. If switch to the tmux pane, relative number is still effective in Neovim.